# Jenkins: Jenkins send build notification for a job even before it actually complete

Tags: email, build, jenkins, notifications

some times (not always), jenkins is sending the job failure notification, even though the job is actually not completed. That is, you get the job complete mail. But when you look in to Jenkins, you can see that the same job is still running.

any help will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: And what is the question or problem to solve? Why should jenkins wait for job to complete (clean up,...) in order to send message that job has failed?

Comment: Hi Kojotak, Sorry for the vague question. I just edited it.

Comment: From my experience, Jenkins sometimes get stuck so I've received email too (successful or unsuccessful) but the job was still active and cannot be even stopped.

Comment: Thanks Kojotak. So what would you recommend - restart jenkins server?

Comment: For start check out the logs for exceptions, timeouts and other possible problems.

Comment: @ShaheerAbdulrahiman if you go to the console log for that build, it should say near the bottom of the log that it sent a failure email, so if you check what it says after that it may give some indication